# Ggplot Color Y axis based on the custom breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello I am plotting graph using ggplot2 wanted the Y axis value seperated from custom breaks values, I wanted color them based on the that breaks can anyone suggest me

I tried

```
data=read.table("test",sep='\t', header=TRUE)

ggplot(data,aes(y=perc, x=student)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)) +geom_point(aes(shape=class))+
  labs(x = "students", y = "Percentage") + 
  theme(legend.position = "top", strip.background = element_blank())+scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 30, 50, 70, 95,100))
```

data file

```
perc  student class
90   student1   A10
80   student2   A10
50   student3   A9
60   student4   A9
80   student5   A8
36   student6   A8
25   student7   A9
99   student8   A8
```

I wanted color based on 0-30, 30-50, 50-70, 70-95, 95-100 with different color  blue, red etc

Comment: Please can you use ``dput(head(data))`` rather than sharing a link to a download for your data.

Comment: @user438383  okay I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach with `ggtext` and `glue` to customize your axis labels in next way. You can define any color you want, but the `ggtext` architecture requires the colors with their codes not with their names. Here the code using the sample of data you shared:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)
#Labels
color <- c("#009E73", "#D55E00", "#0072B2", "#000000","#FF6C90","#9590FF")
labs <- c('0','0-30','30-50','50-70','70-95','95-100')
name <- glue("<i style='color:{color}'>{labs}")
#Code
ggplot(data,aes(y=perc, x=student)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)) +geom_point(aes(shape=class))+
  labs(x = "students", y = "Percentage") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 30, 50, 70, 95,100),
                     labels = name)+
  theme(legend.position = "top", strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_markdown())
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
data <- structure(list(perc = c(90L, 80L, 50L, 60L, 80L, 36L, 25L, 99L
), student = c("student1", "student2", "student3", "student4", 
"student5", "student6", "student7", "student8"), class = c("A10", 
"A10", "A9", "A9", "A8", "A8", "A9", "A8"), Cut = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("[0,30]", "(30,50]", 
"(50,70]", "(70,95]", "(95,100]"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

The other option is coloring by range, so you should first create a variable for ranges and then enable the color element in `geom_point()` with that variable:

```
#Second option
#Labels
data$Cut <- ifelse(data$perc>=0 & data$perc<30,'0-30',
                   ifelse(data$perc>=30 & data$perc<50,'30-50',
                          ifelse(data$perc>=50 & data$perc<70,'50-70',
                                 ifelse(data$perc>=70 & data$perc<95,'70-95','95-100'))))
#Code
ggplot(data,aes(y=perc, x=student)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)) +geom_point(aes(shape=class,color=Cut))+
  labs(x = "students", y = "Percentage") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 30, 50, 70, 95,100))+
  theme(legend.position = "top", strip.background = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ansr but here i wanted points to be colored not label

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik I have added an update for what you want. I hope this can help you!

Comment: How can we give a custom color here